# How to Multiply Columns From Different Tables in SQL?

Tags: sql

What I'm trying to do is multiply two columns from separate tables. Below is the query I tried, but I'm getting a syntax error near "*".

```
SELECT quantity
FROM includes
INNER JOIN product
ON includes.quantity = product.productprice;
SELECT includes quantity * productprice 
AS totalprice
FROM product
```

Quantity is one of the columns inside of the table "include" and productprice is one of the columns inside the table "product." I used INNER JOIN to try to join these tables together and tried to multiply the two columns together under a new variable totalprice. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Start with a basic SELECT where you JOIN the tables. When you see you get the correct column values, add the multiplication part.

Answer (score 0):

I've corrected the syntax of your query but the columns in the join are surely not the ones noted.
Please replace `column_name` with the names of the matching columns.

```
SELECT quantity * productprice AS totalPrice
FROM includes
INNER JOIN product
ON includes.column_name = product.column_name;
```